# Need to create a webservice to send messages between two versions of the same application

Tags: c#, web-services, mobile

My assignment is to recreate whatsapp by creating both a desktop application and a mobile application and they must be able to send messages(text audio video etc) to one another.

I have created a wpf application in C# using visual studio and my team is currently building the mobile application. We have a firebase database setup that will hold all of our messages i know wish to create a webservice that will allow the applications to fetch the information from the database and then hand it back to the application to display on the front end.

I have researched various web services that are used with sms's but i am not sure if these will do the trick for what i am hoping to achieve. If anybody could point me in the right direction or provide any advice it would be much appreciated.